# how to add value to a new column to a dataframe based on the match of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of two large excel files. The dataframe 1 is always smaller than dataframe 2. The elements of dataframe 1 are unique while in dataframe there can be many elements repeated by ID and with the same code.

I'm trying to add a new column to my dataframe 1, the new column is the 'code' of the dataframe 2 (add the value if the ID of both dataframes match).

I managed to solve this with two nested for loops, but the process is too slow. Is there an alternative to add the new column?.

The following dataframes are very small and are just to illustrate the example, actually I have a large amount of data with a large number of columns.

```
import pandas as pd

details_1 = {'ID':['ID01', 'ID02', 'ID03', 'ID04', 'ID05'],
             'Qty': [1,2,3,4,5]}

details_2 = {'ID':['IDA01' ,'ID03', 'ID01','ID02','IDA02','IDX12' 'IDA03', 'IDA04', 'IDA05', 'ID04', 'ID05'],
             'code': ['ab','yz','acv','abc','efs','xw2','fgt','axf','ard','afd','x01']
}
 
df1 = pd.Datafrme(details_1, columns = ['ID', 'Qty'])
df2 = pd.Datafrme(details_2, columns = ['ID', 'code'])


output: print(df3)

          ID     Qty  new_code 
0         ID01    1    acv           
1         ID02    2    abc              
2         ID03    3    yz              
3         ID04    4    afd              
4         ID05    5    x01
```

Comment: a few errors in your code, you should test your sample code first.

Answer (score 2):

Use merge method instead.

Here is the example code.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "ID")
```

Comment: Hi Gilseung Ahn, thanks for your answer, do you have any idea how I could add the new_code column when there are many more columns in dataframe 1 and in dataframe2? The examples I put only have 2 columns and clearly a merge can be done, since only one column is different